# Android Parent and Child ActivityOrientation

Tags: android, view, screen-orientation

While running a landscape activity and a popup dialog is displayed, which is in a portrait mode, I've noticed that the parent activity was also rotated to portrait mode. Is it not possible to set the orientation of the parent and child activity independently?

**EDIT:** It is not actually a child activity. I am sorry if I've used wrong terminology. It is actually a different activity/application which is loaded while the 1st activity/application is still running. What I have noticed that it is happening in case of the following settings,

1st activity: android:screenOrientation="landscape"
2nd activity(dialog msg): android:screenOrientation="portrait"

Thanks,
artsylar

Comment: I don't think you can set the orientation per view. Orientation is set on activity. Hounshell's idea is a good one by the way, you can add an animation to the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply rotation transformations to child views, but you'll have to take over control of portrait landscape yourself entirely.  There's no built-in way to do that.